# How to switch the native app to web view using Appium

Tags: automation, android-webview, appium-android

how to switch the native app to web view using Appium.

for ex. I have a one e-commerce app and their payment gateway depends on the third party, now the payment details are open in the web view. so, how to manage web view in the native app.